# Ubuntu: install latest version of package

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04 and I need to use stress-ng.

If I type: `apt-cache policy stress-ng`
I obtain:

```
stress-ng:
  Installed: 0.03.15-1~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 0.03.15-1~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.03.15-1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So if I run `apt-get install stress-ng`, it downloads version 0.03.15.
Unfortunately, this version does not allow me to do some things which are present in the last one, 0.07.16, supported by Ubuntu 17.04.
How can I do to use this latest version on 14.04?

Comment: `curl -o- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/tarballs/stress-ng/stress-ng-0.07.16.tar.gz` and then extract with `tar -xvzf stress-ng-0.07.16.tar.gz`, and then copy the "stress-ng-0.07.16" folder to where it would usually be installed.  If `curl -o-` doesn't work try `curl -sL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the repositories of the newer release to `sources.list`,and use `apt-pinning`,this is an advanced feature to install packages from a newer version of Ubuntu.

Check out [Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).

> Pinning is a process that allows you to remain on a stable release of
>   Ubuntu (or any other debian system) while grabbing packages from a
>   more recent version.
>
> Note however that the processes described below will only work if
>   things like libc6 versions match, so you should probably not do this
>   on an Ubuntu system. I strongly recommend you look at UbuntuBackports
>   before doing this.

Also you can just download the package and `make install`.

Hope this helps.